# How to stop MessageBox repetition when LinkLabel in DataGridView column is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

1.This is My Form:

[image]

2.Message pops-up when LinkLabel in DataGridView is clicked:

[image]

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da 
        = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT casetype, caseno, year from cases where casetype = '"
                             + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
    link.Text = "More Information !";
    DataGridViewLinkColumn col2 = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
    col2.Name = "column2";
    col2.HeaderText = "Information";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col2);
    dataGridView1.CellContentClick += 
        new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = link.Text;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString()

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da 
        = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM cases WHERE caseno = '" 
                             + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() 
                             + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();

    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1.Case Type = " 
            + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["casetype"].ToString() 
            + "\n\n2.Case No = " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["caseno"].ToString() 
            + "\n\n3.Case Year = " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["year"].ToString() 
            + "\n\n4.Case Name = " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString() 
            + "\n\n5.Type = " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["type"].ToString() 
            + "\n\nTIME :- " + current.ToString() + "", 
            "Message Box", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
}
```

Now, each time when i provide a new search parameters in the TextBox and click the button3 button the results is shown in the DataGridView with LinkLabel. When i click the LinkLabel a MessageBox pops-up but its repetition increments by 1 when i provide new search parameters in the TextBox and get new data in my DataGridView according to the search parameters. The number of MessageBox increases with number of time i search.
So anyone can please tell me that how to show MessageBox only for once when i click the LinkLabel even after loading the DataGridView by providing different parameters or search using my textbox.

Comment: What do you want to show in message box? Instead of the for loop, you should call the messagebox once and show what you want to show.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - i remove the loop but still the repetation of message box doesn't stops. It increments the number of time when i load my grid with new data. You can see my Screenshot attached with the post :-(

Comment: Also you are adding `CellContentClick` each time you load data.

Comment: @RezaAghaei do u have any alternative way. What i want to achieve is when i load new data in grid by providing different parameters in textbox and then click on search. A new linklabel column is added and when i click that label that particular row is been shown in message box.

Comment: Also `LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();  link.Text = "More Information !";` does nothing for you. You should manipulate `col2`, for example `col2.UseColumnTextForLinkValue=true` and set `col2.Text="More Information !"`

Comment: [How to accepting an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message box shows multiple times because:

- You put your message box in a loop. Call the message box only once and pass it what you need to show. If you want to show multiple messages, you can put messages in separated lines in message box.
- Also you are adding [`CellContentClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) each time you load data. Add the handler once. You can move the code that assign the handler to event, to your form load event.

Also to check if the clicked cell is the one that you want:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the clicked cell is your link label column (at index =3)
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex>=0)
    {
        //e.RowIndex is the index of clicked row
        //Use this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] to find the clicked row.
    }
}
```

To set the text for the link label column, you should manipulate the link label column and creating a link label control is useless, for example if col2 is your link label column:

```
col2.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
col2.Text="More Information !";
```

Comment: thnks for the solution. You were right i was generating the event handler twice for which i was incrementing the messagebox pop-up count. silly mistake ! :-)